# EFCore - Select After Group By

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
List<int> data = dbContext.table
.GroupBy(x => x.Date)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
.Take(1)
.SelectMany(x => x.Select(c => c.Id))
.ToList();
```

With this query, i want to get all ids with the latest date.
But I get an error for this query using EFCore.(But this works just fine using EF not EFCore).
Error says ;

> "The LINQ expression ... could not be translated. Either rewrite the
> query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation
> explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable',
> 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'."

I am curious why it works in Ef but not EFCore?

Comment: The question's query wouldn't make much sense in SQL. In SQL a GROUP *collapes* rows and returns only aggregate values. `.SelectMany(x => x.Select(c => c.Id))` doesn't make sense because the group isn't supposed to have multiple rows any more. What are you trying to return ?

Comment: Are you trying to return the last row per date? `Max(x=>x.Id)`. Or all rows for the latest date? Even in SQL you'd need a subquery to find that last value

Comment: Looks like all the ids with the latest date.

Comment: i want to get all ids with the latest date.

Comment: *"...why it works in Ef but not EFCore?"* Because they are different libraries? With different LINQ query translation implementations, with EfCore still not supporting many LINQ patterns?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL a GROUP BY clause *collapses* rows and returns a single row per group. That row can only contain the group columns and aggregate rows. `.SelectMany(x => x.Select(c => c.Id))` doesn't make sense in a GROUP BY query.

I suspect the query is trying to retrieve the IDs for the latest date. In SQL that requires a subquery to find that latest date:

```
SELECT ID
FROM TheTable
Where Date=(SELECT MAX(Date) 
            FROM TheTable)
```

The equivalent in EF would be :

```
var ids=dbContext.TheTable
                 .Where(t=>t.Date==dbContext.TheTable.Max(r=>r.Date))
                 .Select(t=>t.Id)
                 .ToList();
```